# Show hidden div in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a website I have its main page HTML file but unfortunately, I am not able enough to find its hidden div which I am able to see in view-source of the page. I am new here maybe my question is not proper but I need your help. There are 2 videos I want to target them to change them a little bit. thanks in advance. 
my target code is here which can be get by playing the video from inspect element.

```
<div class="html5-video-container" data-layer="0"><video tabindex="-1" class="video-stream html5-main-video" controlslist="nodownload" style="width: 905px; height: 509px; left: 230.556px; top: 0px;" src="blob:https://www.youtube.com/1c547a9c-424b-42f4-a527-536078a60662"></video></div>



 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">


  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">

  <title>Cube Animation</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Cube Animation">
    <meta name="DC.Title" content="Accueil">
    <meta name="DC.Creator" content="uncanny valley studio">
    <meta name="DC.Rights" content="uncanny valley studio">
    <meta name="DC.Publisher" content="uncanny valley studio">
    <meta name="DC.Description" content="Cube Animation">
    <meta property="og:title" content=" Cube Animation">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">

    <meta itemprop="name" content="Cube Animation">
    <meta itemprop="description" content="Cube Animation">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bundle.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/3d_random_builder.css">
  <style>
  #thumbholder,.logo{
    opacity:0;
     -webkit-transition: all 2s ease 0s;
    transition: all 2s ease 0s;
  }
  .showon{
    opacity:1!important;
  }
  </style>
  </head>
<body class="body" style="height: 11840px;">


<div class="toggle">
<span class="header-logo">
    <img src="images/logo-white.png">
</span>


</div>




<nav class="navigation visible" style="visibility: visible;">
    <div class="logo visible">

    <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
</div>
<div class="close">✕</div>

  <ul id="thumbholder">

  </ul>

 <div class="socials" style="display:none;">
<a href="" target="_blank">
<img class="instagram" src="images/instagram.svg">

</a>
<a href="" target="_blank">
<img class="facebook" src="images/facebook.svg">
</a>
</div>
</nav>
<div class="css3d-container"><div style="overflow: hidden; width: 1000px; height: 740px; position: absolute; top: 0px; perspective: 640.859px; display:none;"><div style="transform-style: preserve-3d; width: 1600px; height: 740px; transform: translateZ(640.859px) matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -925.759, 1) translate(800px, 370px);">

<div id="allslideholder">


</div>
</div>

</div></div>
<div id="ajax-data">
<div class="face-warper" data-id="projets" data-position="0" data-ratio="big"></div>
</div>
<div class="background"></div><div class="arrow visible">
<img class="arrow-image" src="images/arrow.svg">
</div><footer></footer>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tween.js/16.3.5/Tween.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/loadalldata.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   loadimgdata();
})




</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: which div you are looking to find

Comment: This is the piece of code I want to access.  
<div class="html5-video-container" data-layer="0"><video tabindex="-1" class="video-stream html5-main-video" controlslist="nodownload" src="blob:https://www.youtube.com/14f59fe9-1207-4aca-a07a-7b01ed64dcd2"></video></div>

Comment: Try whether this works for you? `$('.video-stream html5-main-video')`

Comment: did not work sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be in this file you need to find in other files of your project any java script  file where this function is defined.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is you need to add that div with in the body of your HTML page. Then check the URL you are adding in src. it is not correct. Either check for correct url or you can download the video and can put it under project folder and can then display it.